# How should I terminate a range hood exhaust duct through a wall?

Tags: vent, pest-control, stove, exhaust-vent

I discovered that my home's overhead stove vent doesn't actually vent to anywhere. So I've pulled out the old fan, purchased a new, more powerful fan with 1000 CFM, and then added 8" pipes through the attic. These pipes travel about 10 ft and will exit out an 8" hole out the front siding of the house, in the second floor. What type of product do I buy to allow the air to vent, without letting in much cold air, bugs, and mice?

I think this gooseneck product might be good, but the promotional flyers with it show that installed on the roof, and they don't show a solution exiting out the siding of the house.

[image]

Comment: **8 inch wall vent hood** in your search engine of choice, and you can write your own answer....

Comment: That one is for a roof.  There are ones for walls.  They have gravity- or spring- loaded flaps to reduce unwanted air flow when off.

Answer (score 1):

You have many to choose from just by searching "wall vent". One that I have installed on nunerous occasions is shown below from Walmart. It fits into an 8" duct and has about a 9.25" flange to fasten to the wall. It sits flat against the wall which is a nice feature. These all have bug screens that will have to be cleaned once in a while

[image]